# heuristic pickup and delivery problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-science

I need to solve several small pickup and delivery problems with time windows (one vehicle serving 4-5 orders, each of them having a pickup location, delivery destination, and deadline) with high accuracy. Are you aware of any computationally efficient heuristic that performs well for such small problems?

Comment: Show us the problem.

Comment: Here is a simple example with two orders: given a start location S, order 1 with pickup point P1 and destination D1, order 2 with pick up point P2 and D2, find the optimal sequence among: {S,P1,D1,P2,D2; S,P1,P2,D1,D2; S,P2,P1,D2,D1; etc.} such that total cost is minimized and deadlines are not violated.

Comment: If you have just 10 points to travel between, you can brute force all possible options within a second or so on any modern computer.